# database two column logical OR index, or create separate 'index' table

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, database-design

I have this following table:

```
Matches -> match_id, team_a_id , team_b_id, score
```

This table will record matches between two teams (team A and team B). However, sometimes team A play as the host and sometimes team B plays as the host. Therefore, when I tried to find history matches between team a and team b. What I currently I am doing is to

```
select * from matches where (team_a_id = 1 and team_b_id = 2) or (team_a_id = 2 and team_b_id = 1);
```

Is there any better approach to such case? As for the query above, am I right to include index of combination team_a_id and team_b_id? But even so, then I still have a Logical OR condition between AB OR BA.

**Alternatively**,
I have another idea, that is to have another table let say history

```
History -> team_hash, match_id
```

I manually build team_hash where `hash(a,b) == hash(b,a)`. But this result in slightly slower insert but faster read. Or is it really faster read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is a composite index on `{team_a_id, team_b_id}`, the DBMS can execute your SQL statement using only two index seeks (one for the `team_a_id = 1 and team_b_id = 2` and the other for the `team_a_id = 2 and team_b_id = 1`), which is very fast. I don't expect you should find the performance lacking.

---

However, there is a way to eliminate one of these index seeks. Add a constraint...

```
CHECK(team_a_id < team_b_id)
```

...and encode a "direction" (i.e. which team is host) in a separate field if necessary. This way, you know `team_a_id = 2 and team_b_id = 1` can never be true, so you only need to search on `team_a_id = 1 and team_b_id = 2`.

---

"Symmetrical" hashing is a neat idea, but:

- The correctness of the hash cannot be enforced declaratively - you'll need to do it through a trigger or at the application level.
- It's a redundant data. You'll need to keep `team_a_id` and `team_b_id` anyway to resolve hashing conflicts. Larger data effectively means smaller cache.
- It may actually increase the number of indexes - the efficient enforcement of the referential integrity will probably require indexes on `team_a_id` and `team_b_id` even if you don't need them for the actual SQL query. In addition to putting more pressure on cache, every additional index must be maintained, potentially hurting the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE performance. The situation is especially serious in InooDB where you cannot turn-off the clustering, so secondary indexes tend to be more expensive than in heap-based tables (see the "Disadvantages of clustering" in [this article](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/)).

Comment: uhm btw, is it okay to have a follow up question? let say we have these arrangement so that team_a_id < team_b_id also the direction flag. Then I have another query to get history of team matches. What I have in mind is to run this query: `select * from matches where team_a_id = 1 or team_b_id = 1` then I ended up with similar situation as AB or BA. So I am thinking wouldn't it be better to just duplicate every entry of the matches? so I have `A,B, host` and another record `B,A,away`. Then for my new case, I can quickly do `select * from matches where team_a_id = 1`

Comment: @Fajarmf But then you have 2x rows in the table, diminishing the effectiveness of the cache, and the DBMS has trouble enforcing the presence of both rows. Two index seeks should still be plenty fast, but if you have **measured** the effects eliminating one of them on realistic amounts of data and concluded that the balance of performance for this and other queries is more favorable, go for it. I just wouldn't do it by default - when confronted with a design with smaller data vs. a design with larger data, pick smaller data by default and only reconsider after thorough measurement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your WHERE clause something like this

```
((team_a_id = 1 and team_b_id = 2) or (team_a_id = 2 and team_b_id = 1))
AND team_a_id IN (1,2) AND team_b_id IN (1,2)
```

this way it will be possible to use an index like (team_a_id,team_b_id).

Comment: Why is it that coding these where clause at the end enable me to use only team_a,team_b index?

Comment: It will enable you to use one of `(team_a_id)`, `(team_b_id)`, `(team_a_id,team_b_id)` or `(team_b_id,team_a_id)` indexes. The ones with both columns will be better.